# how to read solr indexing file by powershell

Tags: solr

I have more than ten thousand files that are indexed by solr and the files are available in the solr server. I want to read one Unique from  all the files.

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: does you schema has the unique id for every docuemnt of sorl?

Comment: Yes, We have Unique id for every document.

Comment: can you retrieve  the document with uniqueId?

Comment: Thanks, Abhijit I need to retrieve unique Id. Either via powershell or any other way

Comment: one you get the unique id then based on the id you can retrive the document from solr

Comment: Yes But I don't have unique id, How to get unique id

Comment: you said you have uniqueId...Can you retrive document from solr without id...?check there if you have the id for any document...How did you define the schema of the document? how are you indexing the document?

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Thank you so much for your response. My problem is in solr server we have document with field unique id and i am trying to retrieve all unique id but using solr UI i am not able to retrieve id more than 50000 in one query. Please suggest me to retrieve all unique ids in one query. or if you have any alternative to retrieve the all unique ids.

Comment: here you may need to pass the size as the query param...if that is not working you can send multiple request to solr and get all the documents...while sending multiple requests ...you need to change the from value...first query will have from=0&size=50000...second query will have from=50001&size=50000...but again the question is what will you be doing with 50000 ids at one shot...if you are strong somewhere then fine...if you are using it to display something then you need to think on this approach...

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Thank you so much, The solution you have provided that we have tried but we are getting few duplicate records. so my question is can solr store duplicate records. if yes then my problem solve if no then how to get unique values from solr UI.

Comment: You are getting duplicate records..it means you have not defined the unique field in the schema.xml...if you define that then solr does not store the duplicate records..

Comment: Thanks Abhijit. Now issue has been resolved. Thank you so much for your great help.